# Nginx redirecting with different header

Tags: nginx

I am a bit stuck on something. On accessing nginx, if a match "/0" is found at the end of the URL, I would like to remove that match from the URL and add a header. If the match is not found, I would like to add a different header.

Example:

```
www.mysite.com/ex/Z -> goes to www.mysite.com/ex/Z with header "A"
www.mysite.com/ex/Z/0 -> goes to www.mysite.com/ex/Z with header "B"
```

I tried this unsuccessfully. The redirection works, but of course it always adds header 'A':

```
    location ~ ^(.*)/0$ {
        rewrite ^(.*)/0$ $1;
        add_header ... 'B';
    }

    location /ex/ {
        add_header .... 'A';
    }
```

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^(.*)/0$ $1 break;` for your rewrite statement.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and did not work but I think it was because I had to do something else with the name and for some reason it broke. Now I tried from scratch and it seems to work (I found also a solution by setting variables, but your comment is more efficient).

Comment: Is it not inefficient to have treated the URL in the `location` and having to do it again in the `rewrite`? Can't this be done only once?

Comment: You could replace your `rewrite` statement with `try_files $1 =404;` and use the capture form the first regular expression.

Comment: Very neat. Thank you.